# mysql varchar(255) only storing numbers upto 4 decimal place , why?

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a mysql table created by some other devloper, one of the column need to contain numerical values(with upto 10 decimal), i am updating the column with new decimal values(upto 10 decimal places), but when i am updating that column with the new values which are generated using a python script, numbers are automatically getting rounded to 4 decimal places while getting updated in table. the datatype for column is varchar(255), should i alter the column type to FLOAT(11,10).

Comment: Yes `float` as a datatype for a column makes more sense than `varchar` to save numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use the [decimal data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

```
decimal(14,10)
```

this is max number +9999,999999999 min number -9999,999999999 (this is 4 for the integer part, and 10 digits for the decimal part). (you can use other combinations).

Comment: in the mean time i changed the column type using ALTER TABLE thing, but it is taking too much time to change the table, is it normal (taking this much time), in table i have total 300 thousand rows, and ALTER TABLE command is running since last 45 minutes, should i wait for it to finish.

Comment: **never change the type of a column**... create a new column, copy everything to there and see if you like the result (using an update statement, you might need to do cast and type conversions...). If you do drop the original column, create a new column and move everything again...

Comment: ok, i'll cancel this ALTER TABLE query, and do the way you explained. thanks

Comment: Your ALTER TABLE statement implies mysql will have to re-write every single row of the table including the new column. Since you have more than 300k rows, I would definitely expect it takes a significant amount of time, during which your server will likely be mostly IO-bound